# Search in large txt file optimization

Tags: python, txt

I have written a Python code to retrieve information from txt files.I have various databases that I need to search line by line. The main problem is that all the files weigh more than 10 gigabytes. How can I modify and optimize my code to work with large files?

When searching, the app goes into status "not responding" until the search is complete. Usually the search takes about 6+ minutes. I would like to get faster results.

```
import os
import concurrent.futures

def format_matching_line(line, query):
    formatted_line = line.replace(query, f"<span style='background-color:#685581'>{query}</span>", 1)
    return formatted_line

def search_in_file(directory, filename, query):
    matching_lines = []
    words_to_search = query.split()
    filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(file, start=1):
            line = line.strip()
            if all(word.lower() in line.lower() for word in words_to_search):
                matching_lines.append((filename, f"Line {line_number}: {line}"))
    return matching_lines

def search(query, directory):
    results = []
    if query and directory:
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            future_to_file = {executor.submit(search_in_file, directory, filename, query): filename for filename in os.listdir(directory) if filename.endswith(".txt")}
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_file):
                filename = future_to_file[future]
                try:
                    matching_lines = future.result()
                    if matching_lines:
                        results.append(f"Results in {filename}:")
                        for filename, line in matching_lines:
                            formatted_line = format_matching_line(line, query)
                            results.append(formatted_line)
                            results.append('-' * 70)
                        results.append('')
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error while searching in {filename}: {e}")
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    query = input("Введите текст для поиска: ")
    directory = input("Введите путь к папке с файлами: ")
    search_results = search(query, directory)
    for result in search_results:
        print(result)
```

Comment: If you really need to search such massive text files line by line, the only way to speed up this process is to parallelize the search and likely to use a faster language (e.g. C++).

Comment: @bob This won't necessarily help much if the search is I/O bound.

Comment: You should look into using a proper database with a full text index rather than plain text files to store your data if there are going to be multiple queries on the same dataset.

Comment: This also seems like a good use case for [`grep`, `awk` and friends](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55359/how-to-run-grep-with-multiple-and-patterns).

Comment: Some minor, easy speedups: convert the query to lowercase *once*, and convert each line read from the file to lowercase *once*, rather than repeating both of these operations for each iteration of your innermost loop.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly your code is already pretty optimized but I just want to mention a few things in case they can help out at all:

### Possible Optimizations and/or Considerations

#### Indexing

Based on how often your records are changing this might be a viable option. @Luatic mentioned this a bit above.

#### Memory Mapping

For your `search_in_file()` helper you might be able to use something like the `mmap` lib. In layman's terms this would basically allow you to load the file in as chunks instead of loading the whole thing into memory while still letting you have random access to it as if it were in memory.

Here is an example if it helps:

```py
import os
import mmap

def search_in_file(directory, filename, query):
    matching_lines = []
    words_to_search = query.split()
    filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        # Create a memory-map to the file
        with mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as mmapped_file:
            for line_number, line in enumerate(iter(mmapped_file.readline, b""), start=1):
                # Decode the line from bytes to string and strip leading/trailing white spaces
                line = line.decode('utf-8').strip()
                if all(word.lower() in line.lower() for word in words_to_search):
                    matching_lines.append((filename, f"Line {line_number}: {line}"))
    return matching_lines
```

#### Multi Processing Instead Of Multi Threading

This might be a bit of a stretch but python's GIL can sometimes cause issues with CPU bound tasks from taking full advantage of multi threading since threads in the same process cannot execute python bytecode in the typical parallel fashion. Based on the hardware you are using, you could try `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

#### Optimize Your Line Search

As @jasonharper mentioned above instead of converting each line to lowercase this could instead be done on the query itself. This would allow you to only have to do the conversion once instead of for every line in the file.

I am not sure what your DB schema looks like but here is an example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(column) LIKE '%search_term%'
```

#### Random Side Notes

1. If you are trying to figure out where your bottlenecks are the `cProfile` lib can be very helpful in my opinion.
2. Consider using something like ElasticSearch which is designed for this type of task.

Comment: *"letting you have random access"* - What is that good for here? Are you actually using that?

Comment: *"this would basically allow you to load the file in as chunks instead of loading the whole thing into memory"* - You say that as if their way didn't have that already. Why?